# NullPointerExceptions only on some Samsung Galaxy devices?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, libgdx, galaxy

I'm using LibGDX. When my app starts, it creates a Screen. When the Screen is loaded, it calls a static function `Module.createStyles()`.

This function creates a bunch of styles that will be used throughout the rest of the application (built-in LibGDX styles like WindowStyle, LabelStyle, TextButtonStyle - all of the types of things used to create the user-interface objects).

When the Screen is done, it calls `Module.disposeStyles()`.

Anyway, according to my Google Analytics crash reports, I randomly get a **NullPointerException** when trying to, for example, create a Dialog with *Module.dialogStyle*:

`ExitDialog exitDialog = new ExitDialog("Are you sure?", Module.dialogStyle);`

```
Thread: GLThread 2089, Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: style cannot be null.
at package.Window.setStyle(Window.java:181)
at package.Window.<init>(Window.java:63)
at package.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:65)
at package.ExitDialog$1.<init>(ExitDialog.java:38)
```

There is absolutely no reason *Module.dialogStyle* should be null.  The only place I null this field is in `Module.disposeStyles()` and this function is only called in one specific place in the application (at the very end).

I would assume this was a bug in my code somehow even though 95% of users never experience it.  However, all 5% that do experience it seem to be Galaxy users and I'm not sure if that's a coincidence:

- Galaxy S4
- Galaxy S III
- GALAXY Tab 3 lite

Anyone have any ideas?  Don't Galaxy devices have a built-in RAM manager?  Would that have something to do with this?

Comment: Probably the garbage collection is new and improved to be the best in the Galaxy so the device always has more ram than the competition.  I had problems in general (don't have a galaxy) in code that saves the context in a global field.  Once these were removed many issues went away.  Also I don't use onDispose onDestroy anymore I do all cleanup in onStop.

Comment: Not sure why your style suddenly pointed to null with Galaxy devices and it might be hard to figure it out without testing it on those devices. You could add a null check for the style before creating the dialog & for the case of a null style fire a Google Analytics event with some more infos added. (and exit the screen without dialog..) That way at least the users don't really notice the bug and you can still keep tracking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that:

```
Module.dialogStyle
```

is a reference to a `static` property on the `Module` class.

You are probably running into side-effects of how Android manages the life-cycle of JVMs.  There are scenarios (especially on bigger devices) where a JVM instance will be re-used that can cause problems (static initializers will have already been run, for example, and will not re-run).  Alternatively, `static` pointers may live from a previous run of your application into the next, and may have invalid or incorrect state in them.  It depends on the particulars of how your app is organized.

If you include more of the code that shows how and when you initialize the static fields, we can probably figure it out.

For more details on the different lifecycles and how to reproduce them locally, see:
http://bitiotic.com/blog/2013/05/23/libgdx-and-android-application-lifecycle/

Comment: Yeah, you're right about it being a static property. Interesting though, I didn't know that just parts of your app can be compromised in memory, I thought it was everything or nothing. I think I can get away with checking these static members when `onResume()` is called and verifying that they still exist.